# Can`t save any file to SDCard

Tags: java, android, file

I know that there was loads of threads, but I think I read them all. Nothing helped in my case. So first my code:

```
File savePlace; 
if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()))
    savePlace = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File (savePlace.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/MY_APP");
dir.mkdirs();               

String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);

outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
outStream.write(data[0]);
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();

Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length + " to " + outFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

And now my Manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

So I can't figure what's wrong with my application.
I'm checking if there is card and if I can read/write to it. I'm giving absoulte path to file. But after all my app saves files to internal storage of DCIM/MY_APP. Here is log from the end.

```
01-10 21:35:34.005: onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: 1 to /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/MY_APP/1420922134007.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the Android SDK refers to as [internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) and [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) are both part of the on-board flash. The Android SDK, prior to Android 4.4, had no support at all for [removable storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) (a.k.a., "SD card").

Hence, it would appear to be writing to the proper place. Why you are choosing to write only one byte there, I cannot say.

If you are looking to store digital photos, though, rather than manually putting `DCIM` in a directory name, use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)`, to get the device's natural location for digital photos.

Also:

- Call `getFD().sync()` on your `FileOutputStream` after `flush()` and before `close()`
- Be sure that you are doing all of this disk I/O on a background thread
- Consider using `MediaScannerConnection` and `scanFile()` to get your file indexed by the `MediaStore`, so that it will show up when users connect their device via a USB cable to a desktop OS and browse external storage

Comment: I had no idea, about that both refers to on-board flash. Now I`m thinking that maybe I should abandon saving anything to removable storage. Thanks for contribution and for advices!